# XMPP vs JMS as a message carrier

Tags: jms, xmpp, agents, agents-jade

I'm considering using either XMPP or JMS as the transport for exchanging messages between software agents. (I'm working with the JADE agent system.)

The main problem I need to solve is to be able to send or deliver messages from/to agents which may be behind firewalls. Is there any reason to consider XMPP or JMS superior for that purpose?

Answer (score 1):

We do operate some JMS communication through firewalls. The settings of the firewall are depending on your JMS provider, as JMS is not a "wire protocol" but an API. There may be JMS implementations that are hard to manage through a firewall. We used JBOSS MQ and SonicMQ and found it very unproblematic: Both require only a small set of ports to be opened.

One issue that you should keep track on is the behaviour when there is no message traffic: most implementations do not exchange network data as long as no message is sent, most firewalls do have some timeout on a connection. This may lead to connections getting dropped by the firewall. The workaround that we are using here is to recreate the connection once in a while.

Comment: you should probably also take in consideration your platform support regarding JMS and XMPP. In android for example, there is asmack which provides a decent XMPP support but no equivalent for JMS